# MySQL Insert from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I'm having a little trouble with my insert statement this morning.  Yes, I am using the deprecated mysql_query function.  My insert statement looks as follows:

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO ".$db_prefix ." offer_det 
          (fname, lname, 10k, 14k, 18k, 21k, 22k, 24k, 925, coins, bars) 
           VALUES '".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$_10k."', '".$_14k."', 
                  '".$_18k."', '".$_21k."', '".$_22k."', '".$_24k."', 
                  '".$_925."', '".$coins."', '".$bars."')";

$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

My PHP form values are all the variables listed in the first part of the insert statement, 'fname', etc.

My variables are set to pull from the post and are listed as the values going into the insert.

I had to change the variables to underscore before they started, I guess PHP didn't like that.

My questions:

1. Are those 10k, 14k, etc, okay mysql table row names?
2. Is there an issue I'm missing here?

The datatype for `fname` and `lname` are varchar and for the 10k through bars are decimal (7,3).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql - could be useful :)

Comment: try to print the result sentence with "echo $query3;" Maybe it'll become more easy to find a mistake.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html MySQL naming rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column name `925` must be quoted using backticks.

```
(`fname`, `lname`, `10k`, `14k`, `18k`, `21k`, `22k`, `24k`, `925`, `coins`, `bars`)
```

You may also want to consider changing the column names to something else to avoid further similar problems in the future.

Comment: the 10k and similar column names are OK, according to the schema object naming guide of MySQL, as they are not consisted solely of numbers...

Comment: Yes, I just read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql) that pebbl posted in the comments and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm new to PHP / MySQL in general.

Comment: I always go with back-ticking anyway - it's safer in my eyes as you avoid the possibility of problems, and I can't think that it adds that much overhead to query parsing. So this answer still gets +1 from me due to my biased opinion :)

Comment: My updated query is as follows: $query3 = "insert into ".$db_prefix."offer_det (`fname`, `lname`, `10k`, `14k`, `18k`, `21k`, `22k`, `24k`, `925k`, `coins`, `bars`)  
       values ('$fname', '$lname', '$_10k', '$_14k', '$_18k', '$_21k', '$_22k','$_24k', '$_925', '$coins', '$bars')";
echo $query3;
$query_exec=mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());

I'm still not getting any action on this -- Those values are backticked

Comment: Looks like there's no column bars in the table, that might be what's holding it up.  Man, it's early.

Answer (score 1):

You should quote the `925` column name, as per [MySQL Schema Object names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

So correctly:

```
$query3 = "insert into ".$db_prefix."offer_det (fname, lname, 10k, 14k, 18k, 21k, 22k, 24k, `925`, coins, bars)
values 
('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$_10k."', '".$_14k."', '".$_18k."', '".$_21k."', 
'".$_22k."','".$_24k."', '".$_925."', '".$coins."', '".$bars."')";
```

Another recommendation: you should [escape the incoming strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), because SQL injection is a nasty thing to experience...

Answer (score 0):

Use the QUERY as like follow..

```
$query3 = "insert into ".$db_prefix."offer_det (fname, lname, 10k, 14k, 18k, 21k, 22k, 24k, 925, coins, bars) 
       values ('$fname', '$lname', '$_10k', '$_14k', '$_18k', '$_21k', '$_22k', 
       '$_24k', '$_925', '$coins', '$bars')";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
```

And for inserting a variable you need to use single codes only..

Answer (score 0):

Can I be bold and suggest a change in your implementation?

```
/// put your vars in an easier to use format
$insert = array(
  'fname' => $fname,
  'lname' => $lname,
  '10k' => $_10k,
  /* and so on ...*/
);

/// considering you are using mysql_query, use it's escape function
foreach ( $insert as $field => $value ) {
  $insert[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

/// pull out the keys as fields and the values as values
$keys = array_keys($insert);
$vals = array_values($insert);

/// the following should auto backtick everything... however it should be
/// noted all the values will be treated like strings as you were doing anyway
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . $db_prefix . "offer_det` " . 
         "(`" . implode('`,`', $keys) . "`) " . 
         "VALUES ('" . implode("','", $vals ) .  "')";
```

Comment: Pebbl, I appreciate this.  I'm kind of following a structure that I've seen previously.  I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I should change to MySQLi early on to learn the new structure and habits.  Unfortunately I'm on a deadline right now, so I need to produce some results fairly quickly.  All of these functions are on an encrypted and credential required page, but nonetheless I agree that it needs to be safer in case the credentials get compromised and or the employees get too tricky and or stupid.