# Use php uniqid in mysql table name results in occasional errors - how do I avoid it?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Without getting into the lengthy details of why, I have a need to auto-generate mySQL tables that utilize a unique table name that incorporates the string generated by PHP uniqid function.  When doing so, I occasionally (not always) get the following query error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''512e1d9518d44_tbl'' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT
>   SUM(p_count) AS 'pcnt' FROM 512e1d9518d44_tbl

I know I could use a simple cross reference lookup table, but is there another way to avoid the error, which I believe is the result of a violation of table naming rules, while still maintaining the table naming non-squential uniqueness?  I've tried single quoting the table name but get the same result btw.

Comment: Here is discussion of valid tablenames, with a link to the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql

Comment: It might be safer to use tbl_ as a prefix.

Comment: make it `tbl_uniqidhere`.

Comment: @dan1111 and Marc B - Makes sense, especially given the answer provided by Jeroen.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your table / column name starts with a number, you have to escape it using backticks:

```
SELECT SUM(p_count) AS pcnt FROM `512e1d9518d44_tbl`
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I'll accept the answer as soon as it allows me to.  Thanks much!  Any reason it does not always error though?