# Query is always fails using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to INSERT students answers to a Table online_exam_marks whose structure is [image]

. I took $_POST values and stored in different variable like `$a,$b,...`  and `$stu_id = $_SESSION["id"];`
perform a query

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO online_exam_marks (stu_id , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) VALUES ( '$stu_id' ,'$a', '$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i','$j')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        render("success.php");  
    }
    else echo "error";
```

when executed this it always prints error.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see more code to determine your issue.

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1.

Comment: I don't understand how Are you allowed to use numbers as table names in MySQL? is a dupe. But we do need more info.

Comment: @OGHaza look at the accepted answer for the dup - http://stackoverflow.com/a/676452/689579 *Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.* Since column names are *Identifiers*, the OP needs to quote the column names that consist solely of digits, ie. `\`1\`,\`2\`,\`3\`,...`. If they are not quoted, then MySQL will interpret them as number values, not column names.

Comment: @Sean ah got it

Comment: I changed col_names as `1`,`2`.. It worked. Thanks  you very guys

Comment: can't we  avoid SQL injection using htmlspecialchars() ,stripslashes(), trim() on the input data?