# Wordpress external DB: error in your SQL syntax - get_var

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

after feeling like sitting hours in front of my code, I thought maybe someone sees my mistake.

I am using wordpress and try to access an external database:
For Example: $test = 2017; Chemp_ID = "1";

```
$mydb = new wpdb (......);
$state = $mydb->get_var("SELECT ablauf FROM ".$test." WHERE chempionid ='". $Chemp_ID."'");
```

**SQL Error:**
[*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2017 WHERE chempionid ='1'' at line 1]*
SELECT ablauf FROM 2017 WHERE chempionid ='1'

I just don't see the synthax error, since the sql output seems to be fine to my eyes: *SELECT ablauf FROM 2017 WHERE chempionid ='1'*
Hope someone is not as blind as me

Thank and kind regards
Daniel

Comment: Thank for the hint, that this issue has already been answered.

Comment: But this unfortunately the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql) does not solve my problem. :(