# Cannot create table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a table with variables passed into my php file. However, the SQL does not work when I pass in '12345' and works when I pass in 'a12345' instead.

This is my error that is given.

```
Error creating the table 
query was
CREATE TABLE 123456 ( humidity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, temperature VARCHAR(50) 
NOT NULL, gasquality VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
mysqlerror:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'123456 ( humidity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, temperature VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
gasq' at line 1
Creating database failed!
```

and my function that creates the table

```
function CreateTableNode(&$formvars)
{

    $serialno = $formvars['serialno'];

    $qry =  "CREATE TABLE ".$serialno." (".
            " humidity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ".
            " temperature VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ".
            " gasquality VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ".
            " timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

    if(!mysqli_query($this->connection,$qry))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to be able to create tables with numeric names like '12345' or '154124' for other purposes. Thanks alot!

Comment: duplicate of [Are you allowed to use numbers as table names in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

- Provide a prefix to the table you created.
- Moreover, I couldn't
  see the primary key in your table. However, it is not necessary to
  have it but if your table design doesn't have a primary key, you need
  to rethink your design. It plays a vital role to join tables.

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
function CreateTableNode (&$formvars) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'test';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', $dbuser, $dbpass);
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
       print "ERROR! : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
     }


    $serialno = $formvars['serialno'];
    $qry =  "CREATE TABLE ".$serialno." ("."
            `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
            `humidity` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `temperature` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `gasquality` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        )";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute();
    $pdo = null;
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the entity was expected. (near "123456" at position 13)

Try adding a prefix to the table name as such

"t_12345"

```
CREATE TABLE t_12345
```

MySql does not allow numeric values as table name.

Comment: It would help if you explained _why_ the solely numeric name is not valid. But no matter, this is a duplicate of another thread that already explains that.

Comment: Documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap some elements in the query with quotes as the duplicated thread mentioned by underscore_d says:

```
 $qry =  "CREATE TABLE '$serialno' (
            'humidity' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            'temperature' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            'gasquality' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            'timestamp' DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

This will fix your syntax errror in the query.

Marking to close the question as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow the creation of tables with names made solely of digits unless the name is quotes. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

```
Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
```

Try quoting the name with backticks (`) or prefix the table name.

Answer (score -1):

The error says "Creating database failed!".

So I assume you haven't selected the database in the connection query. You should do that or select it with "use mydatabase;" first. Of course, you may need to create the database first.

With PDO it would look like:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
```

Please see dbname=myDB which preselects the right db for you.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Using mysql functions, you can use:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname)
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: That is the user's choice of error message. Creating the table works when the table name is valid, so the database is not the problem.

Comment: The user still did not select the database in this code.

Comment: So they didn't post all the code. Unbelievable on SO, I know! But they must be selecting it somewhere, as the query succeeds when the table name chosen is valid. So the table name is the problem.

Comment: Yap, looks like that. I misread that. Your feedback was good, but the way you wrote it leaves a bad taste.

Comment: I have no idea where that bad taste came from, as I just wrote the facts, but you can interpret it however you want.