# simple sql script within a bash fails

Tags: sql, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -h 172.17.0.1 -P 13306 -u root -p123<<MYSQL_SCRIPT

USE 1DB;

        CREATE TABLE 111 (
        ID              TEXT,
        TEST_CASE       TEXT
        );

        INSERT INTO 111 (ID, TEST_CASE)
        VALUES ("111", "111");

MYSQL_SCRIPT
```

when run this script, bash returns: 
 **ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '111 (
    ID      TEXT,
    TEST_CASE   TEXT
    )' at line 1**

Answer (score 2):

Possibly look at this answer - [Are you allowed to use numbers as table names in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676451/are-you-allowed-to-use-numbers-as-table-names-in-mysql) - and more specifically the line 'Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.'

You could try this:

```
USE 1DB;

    CREATE TABLE '111' (
    ID              TEXT,
    TEST_CASE       TEXT
    );

    INSERT INTO '111' (ID, TEST_CASE)
VALUES ("111", "111");

MYSQL_SCRIPT
```